# Mogrify Image Resize

Tags: image, resize, mogrify

I need to resize several hundred images in a folder to have a minimum of 500px either height or width to meet eBay req's.  Just looking for a command to run from within that directory.  The trick is some images are longer and some are taller so I need a command that will take the greater of the two dimensions and resize it to 500px while maintaining aspect ratio.